# Find n, where its factorial is a product of factorials

Tags: algorithm, math, factorial

Stackoverflow promoted this mathematics [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440482/find-n-where-its-factorial-is-a-product-of-factorials?utm_medium=ad&utm_source=http-stackoverflow-com-questions-14746332-phpexcel-make-first-row-bold&utm_campaign=math.stackexchange.com-promo&utm_content=1440482) at the right pane from stackexchange mathematics site.

I got curious to see the answers. Turned out that the question was about a specfic case `(3!⋅5!⋅7!=n!)` and the answers were for this specfic case too.

From a programmer/programming point of view I wonder what would be the most suffecient algorithm to solve the problem.

We have two situation though. One that the problem always have an answer and the other doesn't.

**Input is 3, 5, 7 and output is 10 as in the linked question.**

Comment: what problem exactly you are trying to find an algorithm? what is the input and output? (it's ambiguous for me)

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A034878 for some references.

Comment: Is it always exactly 3 inputs?

Comment: Ofcourse it could be more. Lets say its an input k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm would be reasonably straightforward:

- Order inputs a, b, and c so that a <= b <= c
- c! can be divided out from n!
- This makes a! * b! equal to the product of numbers between c+1 and n, inclusive
- Find the next prime p > c. This number cannot be produced by multiplying a! * b!, because both a and b are strictly less than p, hence they do not contain p among their factors
- Try all candidate n between c+1 and p-1, inclusive
- If you do not find an answer, there is no solution

In case of a=3, b=5, and c=7 you find the next prime above 7, which is 11, and try all numbers between 7+1 and 11-1, inclusive (i.e. 8, 9, and 10) as candidates for n.

Comment: Wouldn't this require big integers to compute the actual factorials?

Comment: @IVlad Not necessarily: one could solve it by factoring small numbers, and performing subtractions on two sets of factors.

Answer (score 0):

Factor `a!, b!, c!, ...`. For a given prime `p` of `a`, it appears in `a!` this many times:

```
floor(a / p) + floor(a / p^2) + ...
```

For example, `5` appears in `26!`:

```
26 / 5 + 26 / 25 = 5 + 1 = 6 times
```

Now you can binary search your `n` and check if each of the prime factors in `a!*b!*c!*...` occurs exactly as many times in `m!`, where `m` is the middle point of one of your binary search iterations.

Comment: Can you please provide a full example? I couldn't understand everything. It was hard for me :)